# mapstruct target object set multiple times instead of update

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

Below is my mapper interface. I am using `mapstruct 1.3.0.Final`.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ApiMapper {
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "in.entityName.fn", target="name.fn"),
        @Mapping(source = "in.entityName.ln", target="name.ln"),
        @Mapping(source = "in.salute.sln", target="name.salutation"),
    })
    public MyOutput map(InputData in);
}
```

It looks super simple, but the implementation class sets the `name` object in the target twice, so I get only the last mapped object. Can someone help me to understand what am I missing or doing wrong here?

```
@Component
public class ApiMapperImpl implements ApiMapper {

    @Override
    public MyOutput map(InputData in) {
        if ( in == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        MyOutput myOutput = new MyOutput();

        myOutput.setName( entityNameToNameDetails( in.getEntityName() ) );
        myOutput.setName( saluteServiceOutputToNameDetails( in.getSalute() ) );

        return myOutput;
    }

    protected NameDetails entityNameToNameDetails(EntityName entityName) {
        if ( entityName == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        NameDetails nameDetails = new NameDetails();

        nameDetails.setFn( entityName.getFn() );
        nameDetails.setLn( entityName.getLn() );

        return nameDetails;
    }

    protected NameDetails saluteServiceOutputToNameDetails(SaluteServiceOutput saluteServiceOutput) {
        if ( saluteServiceOutput == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        NameDetails nameDetails = new NameDetails();

        nameDetails.setSalutation( saluteServiceOutput.getSln() );

        return nameDetails;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with 1.3.1.Final there was a bug around this area that I think was fixed. Otherwise look at the issue tracker, this should work

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should help to mapstruct in this context, adding a simple method, for example :

```
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "in.entityName.fn", target="fn"),
    @Mapping(source = "in.entityName.ln", target="ln"),
    @Mapping(source = "in.salute.sln", target="salutation"),
})
public NameDetails mapNameDetails(InputData in);`
```

Comment: Appreciated!! But, it does not solve my issue. I need to exclusively set the NameDetails into MyOutput. Anyway, I posted answer for my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers from [here](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mappings-with-several-source-parameters) and [here](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances). I like the 2nd option to use `@MappingTarget` to update existing beans. The only new thing is I need to create object for `MyOutput` and use it when calling the map method.

I have modified my mapper code something like below:

```
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "in.entityName.fn", target="out.name.fn"),
    @Mapping(source = "in.entityName.ln", target="out.name.ln"),
    @Mapping(source = "in.salute.sln", target="out.name.salutation"),
})
public void mapNameDetails(InputData in, @MappingTarget MyOutput out);
```

The `Junit` for the above mapper code.

```
@Autowired
private ApiMapper apiMapper;

@Test
public void testApiMapper() {
 MyOutput output = new MyOutput();
 InputData input = createInputData();

 apiMapper.mapNameDetails(input, output);

 assertNotNull(output);
 assertNotNull(output.getName());

 assertEquals("Sridhar", output.getName().getFn());
 assertNull(output.getName().getLn());
 assertEquals("Mr.", output.getName().getSalutation());
}

private InputData createInputData() {
 InputData data = new InputData();

 data.setEntityName(new EntityName());
 data.setSalute(new SaluteServiceOutput());

 data.getEntityName().setFn("Sridhar");
 data.getSalute().setSln("Mr.");
 return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in version 1.3.1.Final 
[Link to bug](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1828)